# Viewflow unable to set TextView Data into other layout

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using android-viewflow at https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow

And I am using DiffViewFlowExample at https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow/blob/master/viewflow-example/src/org/taptwo/android/widget/viewflow/example/DiffViewFlowExample.java

I am unable to set data onto the second and above view. Plainly using

```
tvProfileName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvProfileName);
```

gives a null error, whereas

```
LayoutInflater factory = finalIndividual.this.getLayoutInflater();
View secondLayout = factory.inflate(R.layout.finalindividual_second, null);
tvProfileName = (TextView) secondLayout.findViewById(R.id.tvProfileName);
```

doesn't seem to set any data when `setText();` is used.

The docs only gives an example for the first view and not the second. Thus, I am stuck at this.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the text View2 that comes under "Different Views ->", then you need to make a change in "DiffAdapter.java" for the names array which is defined there...

Comment: I am changing the text of a TextView in one of the layout. Not the title.

Comment: for listview if you want to change, try to create a custom adapter and set that adapter.

Comment: I am changing the data for the SECOND layout when I fling the Viewflow. Not the first one. Apparently, the second layout wasn't included in the example.

Comment: See the DiffAdapter's getView method. you can change there the layout to your own view which ever you want.

Comment: I'm asking for a dynamic layout. Where I can set data anytime I want in the main activity. I don't think you get what I need.